# SSIS Package Design: ETL Best Practices

Tags: ssis

I am looking for a general rule of thumb, best practice or guide line regarding package design. My current design works, but I don’t know if its appropriate. I currently have each step broken out into its own package and I am wondering if its more efficient to group all Extract / Transform / Load 
work by their tables(Subjects);  or by putting the tables into Extract / Transform / Load packages.

Current Design:
Extract_TableA
Extract_TableB
Extract_TableB
Transform_TableA
Transform_TableB
Transform_TableC
Load_TableA
Load_TableB
Load_TableC

Is it more efficient to run full cycle per table?

TableA_ (Extract,  Transform, Load)
TableB _(Extract,  Transform, Load)
TableC _(Extract,  Transform, Load)

Or is it more efficient to have 1 Extract SSIS Package, 1 Transform Package and 1 Load package?

Extract_     (TableA, TableB, TableC)
Transform_  (TableA, TableB, TableC)
Load –         (TableA, TableB, TableC)

Comment: IMHO I think you are missing one of the main advantages of SSIS which is being able to run tasks concurrently. All your suggestions are very sequential. All your suggestions work but ultimately it depends on you data , which process can you combine, the relative timings of each process, are your transforms part of a data flow are you using staging tables. Does doing A before B or B before A make much difference if they are not dependent on each other. The only rule of thumb I would use is which method is fastest and uses the least resources after a bit of trial and error.

Comment: Dave,
Meaning I should use a master package to call them to run in parallel?

MASTER >  Extract A, Extract B, Extract C     >   TransformA, TransformB, TransformC       >   LoadA, LoadB, LoadC

Comment: Is there a reason to have separate packages? Is this a team of developers working on this or just you. Will you ever have run A, B or C or it's own or are these sub tasks of one big task that will always be run as one thing? It is just my preference and I know many would disagree, but I like to keep things together in one place.

Comment: I am the team, there are no other developers here for me to consult with.  These are its own tasks; However, this will eventually grow.  I am currently pulling over a few tables worth of CRM data.  I know once this part is done, we will be looking to bring more data into the Data Warehouse.  

When I started learning Data Warehousing, I was told each step should be as minimal as possible incase anything crashes.  I was also told to separate each part of the ETL step so you’re not holding unneeded connections  while different steps in the process runs.